# How to remove the space around an item in flash (example linked)

Tags: flash, resize, request, space

I have a flash file which is a music player, and it has an space around the player which I dont want it.  The dimantion is 590X300 but the actual player is about 100px, so I do not want to have all this space.  Only the player.  Have a look at the below link:
[Music Player](http://activeden.net/item/decent-player/10176)

As you can see, the player is in the middle of the stage and there are a big space around it.  In fact it is useless.

I tried to decrease the size in HTML object tag but it decreases all the file, therefore the player become as small as invisible.

In the comments of the top website, someone already asked and the developer talked about movie clip, which i have no idea about it, anyway I have the .fla format too, but just dont know how to fix it, as I am a newbie in Flash.

Thanks

Comment: If you have the FLA and a copy of Flash Pro, just resize the document properties and publish a new SWF.

Answer (score 0):

Change the size of the document from properties and republish as suggested. 
If you want to export according to size of stage, make sure that you take screen size.